# Using NFC needs a paid iOS Development team?

Tags: nfc

I am working at a NFC Tag Reading feature and the problem is, that Xcode told me that my Personal development teams do not support the Associated Domains and Near Field Communication Tag Reading capabilities.

For most of those problems apple wrote something like *"Use a paid developer account to fix this problem"* but I am not sure if this is also a problem I can solve by buying the app-dev license.

This is my error message:
[image: Error Message]

And this is my Signing & Capabilities:
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)

Comment: sorry i just forgot to close my question... 
I was not sure if its a paid iOS service so i thought i can ask something like that in Stack overflow... My bad that its not "allowed"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Support wrote its a paid feature.